# How to serialize a Vector3 using binary serializer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to serialize a class which consist of vectors. So, some error pops up when trying to fix that kind of thing. So, I need help how to serialize a vector. Shall I have to convert that into float and serialize and later deserialize that float and retrieve on transform. If yes how?

```
       BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
       BallData ball = new BallData();
       ball.velocity = usergivenvelocity;
       ball.initialposition = position;
       FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentdatapath + "/Level_" + levelnumber.ToString() + ".dat");
       bf.Serialize(file,ball);
```

Comment: Seems Vector3 is not serializable (as well as Quaternion). Wrap it within your own V3 class/struct or serialize each float individually.

Comment: @Everts I dont know how

Answer (score 2):

Vector3 seems to not be serializable. At least, it has been for the last 10 years, maybe it will change with v2017.

In order to serialize a Vector2/3/4 or a Quaternion, you would first create a new version of it:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Vector3Ser
{
    public float x,y,z;
}
```

Use this version in the Ball class instead of the Vector3.

Full class implementation at: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/956047/serialize-quaternion-or-vector3.html